# Double *ngFor in a table - Angular 2

Tags: javascript, angular, loops

I need to create a table based in two loops. I have tried the following:

```
<tbody *ngIf="testCases">
  <tr class="pointer" *ngFor="let car of cars; let bike of bikes">
    <td class="center">{{car?.id}}</td>
     <td class="center">{{bike?.id}}</td>
  </tr>
</tbody>
```

I know the I get the data because I have tried it in `typescript` with `console.log` but when I display it in `HTML` I print `null` for bike

Comment: Could you provide the response data that you want to loop.

Comment: Do you want data from car and data  from bike alternatively?

Comment: No, it is a table with information about 2 different objects (I can not upload the JSON). I get the information perfectly but I do not know if it is possible to make two ngFor for the in the same row

Comment: what makes you think that you can iterate two arrays in the same ngFor?

Comment: angular doesn't support this kinda syntax...

Answer (score 11):

You can use `<ng-container>`. It is a helper element that allows to use `*ngFor`, `*ngIf`, or other structural directives but doesn't actually create HTML content.

```
<ng-container *ngFor="let car of cars">
  <tr class="pointer" *ngFor="let bike of bikes"> 
    <td>{{car.id}} {{bike.id}}</td>
  </tr>
</ng-container>
```

Comment: I have tried it but after using it, it shows no data (no car and no bike). if i need a 3rd one, how should it be? ng-container , ng-container, tr?

Answer (score 3):

If both have same no of records , you can do it like

```
<tr class="pointer" *ngFor="let car of cars; let i = index;">
    <td class="center">{{cars[i]?.id}}</td> // or <td class="center">{{car?.id}}</td>
    <td class="center">{{bikes[i]?.id}}</td>
</tr>
```

Comment: I think it should be `cars[i]?.id` not `car[i]?.id`.

Comment: I keep getting no data in my screen

Comment: @MarioLópez , please post the data you are getting for `cars` and `bikes`.

Answer (score 1):

In your typescript code you can do this:

```
vehicles = (<any[]>cars).concat(<any>[bikes]);
```

And then in your view you can bind it easily like:

```
<tr class="pointer" *ngFor="let vehicle of vehicles">
  <td *ngIf="vehicle.vehicleType === 'car'" class="center">{{vehicle.id}} is car</td>
  <td *ngIf="vehicle.vehicleType === 'bike'" class="center">{{vehicle.id}} is bike</td>
</tr>
```

Comment: I do not want to print it in the same td

Comment: @MarioLópez then you can add an extra field/property to the car and bike class for eg. in car class the field 'vehicleType' will have default value as 'car' and for bike it will be 'bike' and then you can take different actions. Check for my updated answer

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use on the same line, try it as separate rows

```
<tbody *ngIf="testCases">
  <tr class="pointer" *ngFor="let car of cars ">
    <td class="center">{{car?.id}}</td>
   </tr>
  <tr class="pointer" *ngFor="let bike of bikes">
    <td class="center">{{bike?.id}}</td>
  </tr>
</tbody>
```

**EDIT**

if you want on the same row use **`index`** which will hold the array value

```
<tr class="pointer" *ngFor="let car of cars; let x = index;">
    <td class="center">{{cars[x]?.id}}</td>
    <td class="center">{{bikes[x]?.id}}</td>
</tr>
```

Comment: I need the information in the same row. Is it possible to achieve this